# Could Not open Hibernate Session for transaction : JndiException: unable to find UserTransaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, spring-jdbc, jta

I have a JMS Listener which is configured like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location"
            value="file://${jboss.home.dir}/bin/confs.properties" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="TopicConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
        p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />
        
    <bean id="cachedTopicConnectionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="TopicConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${cache.size}" />
        <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
        <property name="clientId" value="${local.consumer.status.clientId}" />
    </bean>
        
    <bean id="commandeStatusTopic" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
        <constructor-arg value="${local.topic.to}" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.al6.borneIntranet.business.jms.CommandStatusMessageListener" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>      
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionListener" class="com.al6.borneIntranet.business.jms.EsbExceptionListener">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedTopicConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedTopicConnectionFactory"/>
      <property name="destination" ref="commandeStatusTopic" />
      <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
      <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
      <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
        <property name="exceptionListener" ref="exceptionListener" />
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="clientId" value="${local.consumer.status.clientId}"/>
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="30000" />
        <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true"/>
        <property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="statusCmd"/>
        <property name="cacheLevel" value="1"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The datasource is configured in another XML like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

  ...DAO stuff...

    <!--  Datasource JNDI -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:DATA_DS" />
        <property name="resourceRef">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean> 
    
    
    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingLocations" ref="mappingList" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${batch.jdbc.showsql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${batch.jdbc.generatestatistics}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${batch.jdbc.usequerycache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.synonyms">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

When I start the application, I have this right after startup, and its tried without never stop (jmsContainer-1, jmsContainer-2...) :

```
2022-12-05 14:13:40,549 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:13:40,549 [jmsContainer-3]  DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [jmsContainer]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT ( HibernateTransactionManager )
2022-12-05 14:13:40,550 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:13:40,550 [jmsContainer-3]  DEBUG - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@655c3d25 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6b9bcffe deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6fa45655 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2aa6c5c5 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2e9770a1 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1b46aeb2 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@569d4571 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4a893a8a unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction ( HibernateTransactionManager )
2022-12-05 14:13:40,550 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:13:40,550 [jmsContainer-3]  DEBUG - Not preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@655c3d25 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6b9bcffe deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6fa45655 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2aa6c5c5 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2e9770a1 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1b46aeb2 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@569d4571 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4a893a8a unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] ( HibernateTransactionManager )
2022-12-05 14:13:40,550 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:13:40,550 [jmsContainer-3]  DEBUG - begin ( AbstractTransactionImpl )
2022-12-05 14:13:40,550 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:13:40,550 [jmsContainer-3]  DEBUG - begin ( JtaTransaction )
2022-12-05 14:13:41,459 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:13:41,458 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sn9ycas1qtnc1p19shb6c|42c2be8d]-AdminTaskTimer]  DEBUG - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@54756a2d -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.] ( ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner )
2022-12-05 14:13:45,559 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:13:45,553 [jmsContainer-3]  WARN  - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'topic://TopicEntrant' - trying to recover. Cause: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: unable to find UserTransaction ( DefaultMessageListenerContainer )
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: unable to find UserTransaction
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:240)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:992)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: unable to find UserTransaction
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform.locateUserTransaction(JBossAppServerJtaPlatform.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.retrieveUserTransaction(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransaction.locateUserTransaction(JtaTransaction.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransaction.doBegin(JtaTransaction.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:474)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:jboss/UserTransaction]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform.locateUserTransaction(JBossAppServerJtaPlatform.java:70)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jboss not bound
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:267)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:667)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)
    ... 13 more
2022-12-05 14:13:45,559 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:13:45,559 [jmsContainer-3]  INFO  - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection ( DefaultMessageListenerContainer )
```

The weird thing is, that it begins to work right after I connect and use my application on the front.
It I check the log, I have this after using the app :

```
2022-12-05 14:15:05,678 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,678 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [jmsContainer]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT ( HibernateTransactionManager )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,679 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,679 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6d683f75 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@63afcca8 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@67905405 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2292c693 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@e2dd623 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@137a81c2 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@762fcfd4 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@42bd39dc unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction ( HibernateTransactionManager )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,679 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,679 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Not preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6d683f75 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@63afcca8 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@67905405 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2292c693 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@e2dd623 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@137a81c2 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@762fcfd4 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@42bd39dc unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] ( HibernateTransactionManager )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,679 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,679 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - begin ( AbstractTransactionImpl )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,679 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,679 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - begin ( JtaTransaction )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,680 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,680 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Began a new JTA transaction ( JtaTransaction )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,680 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,680 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Obtaining JDBC connection ( LogicalConnectionImpl )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,680 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,680 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Obtained JDBC connection ( LogicalConnectionImpl )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,683 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,683 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk5.WrappedConnectionJDK5@6572926d] ( HibernateTransactionManager )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,683 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,683 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@539cacd3] for key [org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource@3ad9e438] to thread [jmsContainer-20] ( TransactionSynchronizationManager )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,683 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,683 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder@58577a34] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@18bd8806] to thread [jmsContainer-20] ( TransactionSynchronizationManager )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,683 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,683 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Initializing transaction synchronization ( TransactionSynchronizationManager )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,721 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,721 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Registering cached JMS Session for mode 0: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:server-38577-1670246009590-1:1:1,started=true} ( CachingConnectionFactory )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,734 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,734 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Bound value [org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder@19989b05] for key [org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory@dbea681] to thread [jmsContainer-20] ( TransactionSynchronizationManager )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,852 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,852 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Registering cached JMS MessageConsumer for destination [topic://TopicEntrant]: ActiveMQMessageConsumer { value=ID:server-38577-1670246009590-1:1:1:1, started=true } ( CachingConnectionFactory )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,861 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,861 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Received message of type [class org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage] from consumer [Cached JMS MessageConsumer: ActiveMQMessageConsumer { value=ID:server-38577-1670246009590-1:1:1:1, started=true }] of transactional session [Cached JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:server-38577-1670246009590-1:1:1,started=true}] ( DefaultMessageListenerContainer )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,867 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,863 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - onMessage BEGIN ( CommandStatusMessageListener )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,868 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,868 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Received reply ...
2022-12-05 14:15:05,887 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,887 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - successfully registered Synchronization ( TransactionCoordinatorImpl )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,887 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,887 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - begin ( AbstractTransactionImpl )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,887 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,887 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - begin ( JtaTransaction )...
2022-12-05 14:15:05,891 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,891 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Obtaining JDBC connection ( LogicalConnectionImpl )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,892 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,891 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Obtained JDBC connection ( LogicalConnectionImpl )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,929 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,929 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Releasing JDBC connection ( LogicalConnectionImpl )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,929 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,929 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - Released JDBC connection ( LogicalConnectionImpl )
2022-12-05 14:15:05,930 INFO  [STDOUT] 14:15:05,929 [jmsContainer-20]  DEBUG - onMessage END ( CommandStatusMessageListener )
...
```

No more error, everything works fine !

What did I miss ?

EDIT :

Weirdly, if I copy/paste the block "sessionFactory" from the datasource xml file into the jmsListener.xml file, it works !

It gives this file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location"
            value="file://${jboss.home.dir}/bin/confs.properties" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="TopicConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
        p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />

    <bean id="cachedTopicConnectionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="TopicConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${cache.size}" />
        <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
        <property name="clientId" value="${local.consumer.status.clientId}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="commandeStatusTopic" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
        <constructor-arg value="${local.topic.to}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory (exact copy from datasource) -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingLocations" ref="mappingList" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${batch.jdbc.showsql}</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${batch.jdbc.generatestatistics}</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${batch.jdbc.usequerycache}</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.synonyms">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.al6.borneIntranet.business.jms.CommandStatusMessageListener" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>      
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionListener" class="com.al6.borneIntranet.business.jms.EsbExceptionListener">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedTopicConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedTopicConnectionFactory"/>
      <property name="destination" ref="commandeStatusTopic" />
      <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
      <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
      <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
        <property name="exceptionListener" ref="exceptionListener" />
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="clientId" value="${local.consumer.status.clientId}"/>
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="30000" />
        <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true"/>
        <property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="statusCmd"/>
        <property name="cacheLevel" value="1"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

But the order of loading the xml beans file is correct, it loads first the datasource xml file with session factory definition, then the jmsqistener.xml file, so I don't understand why it works...

Comment: You appear to use JTA but have configured the `HibernateTransactionManager` which is for local transaction **not** JTA transactions. For the latter you need the `JtaTransactionManager`.

Comment: Hmmm seems weird because everywhere in my App, I have exclusion for JTA lib in pom.xml
I try to use it anyway but had this exception : No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'


In JMX list of beans I just see : 

TransactionManager
com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate

Comment: Your hibernate is configured for JTA so either you need to properly configure a `JtaTransactionManager` (from Spring) so you really use JTA, or stop configuring Hibernate for JTA.

Comment: If I need to configure "properly" it, I assume I had to modify the Jboss conf files because for now it use com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate.
But there is one thing I don't understand, why is this working perfectly when I start using the application ?

Comment: You don't need to configure JBoss, you need to properly configure Spring/HIbernate. You have now configured Spring for local transactions (`HibernateTransactionManager`) and Hibernate for JTA (through the `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform` and `hibernate.transaction.factory_class`. That being said, judging from the logging, is that you aren't really using Spring to drive the transactions. Nonetheless there is some weird stuff regarding setup going on.

Comment: I think I can't configure it properly because I'm stuck with an old Jboss 4.2.3 version and it will be blocking. I just delete the two lines : "hibernate.transaction.jta.platform and hibernate.transaction.factory_class" and it works ! But I don't understand why ^^

Comment: Arf, I spoke too quickly, the JMS works right at startup, but now when I try to use the app itself, it doesn't work : "org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed, org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection, java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit during a managed transaction!".

Seems that by default the transaction are not handled by hibernate anymore and it failed.

Comment: `You cannot commit during a managed transaction` is the key. So you must use JTA. I fail to see what the problem is when replacing `HibernateTransactionManager` with `JtaTransactionManager` and re-instating the JTA properties of hibernate. Could you elaborate on which versions of Hibernate and Spring you are using?

Comment: I just edit my original post, I find a solution but don't understand why it works ^^

Comment: Well I'm a bit skeptic about being a solution, it (kind of) works but still the configuration doesn't make sense. Why moving it around fixed it, no idea without seeing the whole project, how things are loaded etc. I would however suspect that removing the `transactionManager` bean and add `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` should have had fixed things as well (or at least the configuration).

Comment: Ok, so I delete the transactionManager block, and add the tx:jta line.
Now I go back to the old error : "No JTA TransactionManager found at fallback JNDI location [java:/TransactionManager] ( JtaTransactionManager )
org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate] available at JNDI location [java:/TransactionManager] is not assignable to [javax.transaction.TransactionManager]"

I had to add : javax.transaction:jta:1.1 in my pom,but it seems to be a conflict between jta embedded with Jboss (arjuna ?) and jta

Comment: You shouldn't add the dependency as that will lead to duplicate classes being loaded and thus classcast exceptions. You should remove that jar. For compiling/testing you do need that, you can have it with scope `provided` or `test`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250217/discussion-between-user2178964-and-m-deinum).